# Bazaar syntax to ignore directories matching a wildcard

Tags: shell, bazaar

I'm sure this is a dumb question, but what is the syntax to ignore my `_Resharper.*` directories with Bazaar? I've tried ignoring: `\_Resharper*.*` `./\_Resharper*.*`, `**/\_Resharper*.*`, plus variations of those on the wildcards. No matter what I do, it continues to pick up the directory.

Comment: Update: embarrassing thing. I never noticed the directory name was _ReSharper.*. So changed the S to upper case and things are working as expected.

Answer (score 3):

You are probably bitten by the wildcard expansion occuring in the shell.

Type `bzr ignore --help` and look at the Examples section:

- Ignore the top level Makefile: `bzr ignore ./Makefile`
- Ignore class files in all directories: `bzr ignore "*.class"`
- Ignore .o files under the lib directory:`bzr ignore "lib/**/*.o"`
- Ignore .o files under the lib directory: `bzr ignore "RE:lib/.*\.o"`
- Ignore everything but the "debian" toplevel directory: `bzr ignore "RE:(?!debian/).*"`

Comment: `bzr ignore "RE:(?!debian/).*"` doesn't work any more

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use backslash there. Just

```
_Resharper.*
```

or

```
_Resharper
```

will work.

Comment: Actually added that to escape the '_'char.. when I first posted it wasn't showing up. Added it, worked (backslash not visible)... though now both chars show up.

Comment: try using just quotes or double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

**#caution**
At least with version ~2.7.* bazaar will not easily tell you that it is ignoring a **/wildcard/* rule in cases where entities below a matched rule are already versioned (under version control).

example:
`**/vendor/*` still produced entries in `$ bzr st` for me, below *vendor/* until I issued the command `$ bzr remove --keep .` from within the *vendor/* directory